# Convergence of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

For every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ holds that $ - 1\le \sin(x) \leq 1$. So in my opinion the following inequality is true $ -\frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \leq \frac{1}{x}$ and we have $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x}$, $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} -\frac{1}{x} = 0$. But $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \neq 0 $. Where's my fallacy?

Comment: But that limit is zero. Are you thinking of the limit as $x\to 0$? In that case the squeeze theorem won’t work as you’ve set it up.

Answer (score 4):

I think you meant $\lim_{x \to  \infty} \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$, in which case, yes this limit is $0$. What I believe you are confusing this with is an entirely different limit: $\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin x}{x}=1$. Notice one is to infinity, the other is to $0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was exactly the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The inequality you used is just an application of the well-known [Squeeze-theorem.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)
For $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ See:[How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)